# To invoke a method of the main Thead From child thread

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, thread-safety

In my app i am using soap webservice call , based on the webservice call reply i have to display some messages .,

**But after the reply i could not able to do this from the spawned child thread**

So how to get back to the main thread and display this after the reply i got

Hope this is clear.. help me how to achieve my requirement

```
{
Thread t1 = new Thread() {
public void run() {

    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    // There will be delay in this statement while fetching a data from webservice
    String  returnfromWebservice =   webservice(xmlDetails, "generateid");
    Log.v("returnfromWebservice",returnfromWebservice);
    if(  ! returnfromWebservice.equalsIgnoreCase("nil")){ 
        gotid = returnfromWebservice;
        gotReply=true;
    //  dothis();// I could able to do this because this method contains widgets
    //  I am gettin the error : Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    //I understand this is because childthread has no controls on widget 
    /**Suggest me how to get back to main thread*/
    }
    }};
t1.start();
dothis();// so i am doin here after the completion of it 


}

public void dothis{
if(gotReply){
    idtext.setText(gotid);
    genId.setEnabled(false);
    Toast.makeText(WelcomeScorer.this, "Generated ", 500).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(WelcomeScorer.this, "Try Once More ", 500).show();
    idtext.setText(gotid);
}
}
```

I am new to android, Is there any best approach in android api to handle this situation ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following code to touch your ui elements from another thread

```
youractivityname.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

If your thread is in same activity you can use this. Otherwise you should use your activity class object to run the above method.
From your code you should call dothis(); after thread has done its job. From your it will call the dothis method immediately after thread has started it wont care whether thread has done its job or not.

Answer (score 1):

The various methods are documented in [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html). Using [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) is probably the simplest.