# updating view from thread errors

Tags: android

I am bit confused and dont know where to look for. What I want is to refresh screen texts cn & sn every 5 seconds. How can I dow it with this thread? Its the only playce from where i update the textfields.  I managed it with thread messaging/Handler, but its too long. So is there any shorter way?

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
 public void run() {
 while(true) {
    cn.setText(getClName()); //mutated text
    sn.setText(getSN());     //mutated text
    Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
  }
}
};
t.start();
```

I get this kind of errors:

```
 03-22 09:04:22.669: E/AndroidRuntime(7877): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
 03-22 09:04:22.669: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3020)
 03-22 09:04:22.669: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:634)
 03-22 09:04:22.669: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
 03-22 09:04:22.669: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
 03-22 09:04:22.669: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
 03-22 09:04:22.669: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
 03-22 09:04:22.669: E/AndroidRuntime(7877):    at 


 03-22 09:04:28.849: E/global(7877): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
 03-22 09:04:28.849: E/global(7877): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 03-22 09:04:28.849: E/global(7877):    at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
 03-22 09:04:28.849: E/global(7877):    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1280)
 03-22 09:04:28.849: E/global(7877):    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1247)
 03-22 09:04:28.849: E/global(7877):    at android.kvisio.Main.onDestroy(Main.java:298)
```

Comment: Android UI is not Thread Safe so Only the UI therad can update the UI . . . .

Comment: You can not do UI changes from Java thread. You can check [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578548/to-invoke-a-method-of-the-main-thead-from-child-thread/9578652#9578652

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the current Android documentation **Only the UI thread can update the UI**, However to make your system work you can use Handler and send Message to update the UI...see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060068/help-with-handler-class-to-update-ui-android)

You can also use AsyncTask, read a nice blog [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)..

Answer (score 4):

Do this,

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
public void run() {
while(true) {

    YouActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            cn.setText(getClName()); //mutated text
            sn.setText(getSN());     //mutated text
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
  }
}
};
t.start();
```

You must ALWAYS run your UI Activities from the UI Thread. ANdroid has tried to help the developers do this by providing AsyncTask. Try and use that as much as possible. And in case you can't due to requirements, use the runOnUiThread() functionality.

Comment: **This code is right according to your requirement. Here a thread is started for the infinite of time. So don't forget to stop the thread when your activity going to pause and start again when your activity going to resume.**

Answer (score 3):

Declare a class member of type Handler

```
private Handler uiCallback;
```

Then, in your code:

```
uiCallback = new Handler () {
    public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
        cn.setText(getClName()); //mutated text
        sn.setText(getSN());     //mutated text
    }
};

Thread t = new Thread(){
 public void run() {
 while(true) {
    uiCallback.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
  }
}
};
t.start();
```

[This article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) explains your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
cn.setText(getClName()); //mutated text
sn.setText(getSN());
```

here is the problem. to fix you have to make modify the view to the UI thread. To achieve this you can use an `handler`, or if you are inside an activity you can use `runOnUiThread(Runnable)`